# CakePHP 2.0 LinkedIn Plugin - Post a share?

Tags: php, cakephp, share, linkedin-api, cakephp-2.0

I am using this LinkedIn plugins for CakePHP 2.0.4: https://github.com/ProLoser/CakePHP-LinkedIn

*I setup everything to work fine with login and get user's profiles like first name, last name,... using this syntax: $this->Linkedin->find("all",...). I renamed the default name,"Linkedin", of Linkedin datasource to "LinkedinSource", hence I can call my model "Linkedin" just for my convenience.*

I followed the file **/Plugin/Linkedin/Model/LinkedinMessage.php** to create this function in my Linkedin model:

```
function updateStatus($message) {
    $request = $this->request;
    $request['uri']['path'] = 'people/~/shares';
    $this->request = $request;
    //Above 3 lines are used to bypass the error "changing value of overloaded object property has no effect if I use $this->request["uri"]["path"] = "..."

    $data = array(
        'comment' => $message
        , 'visibility' => array('code' => 'anyone')
    );
    //Above settings follow this: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api

    $saved = $this->save($data);
}
```

When I run above code using my own LinkedIn account (connected & authorized), the value of $saved is just **TRUE** but NO status/share is posted to my LinkedIn account when I open my account on a browser (Google Chrome)

I tried to change the URI Path to

```
    $request['uri']['path'] = 'people/~/person-activities';
```

and request data to:

```
    $data = array(
        'content-type' => "linkedin-html"
        , 'body' => $message
    );
```

as in https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/post-network-update but still no better result.

I also change these lines in **/Plugin/Linkedin/Config/LinkedinSource.php**:

```
$config['Apis']['LinkedinSource']['write'] = array(
    // http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1044
    'mailbox' => array(
        'people/~/mailbox' => array(
            'subject',
            'body',
            'recipients',
        ),
    ),
);
```

to

```
$config['Apis']['LinkedinSource']['write'] = array(
    // http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1044
    'mailbox' => array(
        'people/~/mailbox' => array(
            'subject',
            'body',
            'recipients',
        ),
    ),
    //https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api
    'shares' => array(
        'people/~/shares' => array(
            'comment',
            'content',
            'visibility',
        ),
    ),
);
```

but still no better result.

Just be noted I added these lines in **/Plugin/Linkedin/Model/LinkedinMessage.php**

```
    public $startQuote;
    public $endQuote;
```

to avoid these errors:

```
Undefined property: LinkedinSource::$startQuote [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 1269]
Undefined property: LinkedinSource::$endQuote [CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 1269]
```

I dont know if that can cause my problem or not but I want to list all details here.

Please help as I spent almost one day to make this work but still can not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem! The **Content-Type** MUST be **application/json** in order to work! I thought **x-li-format: json** is enough but it is NOT.